# is my script running as a scheduled task?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I have some CMD/ Powershell scripts which may be run from the command line or as a scheduled task.

When in scheduled task, some options may not be available (eg. GUI) and some need to be used differently (eg. error logging to file/ event log instead of screen).

Is there a way to find if the script is currently running as a scheduled task and the name of the scheduled task (for logging purpose)?

If needed, I can use *advanced* programming tools such ad .NET, C#, etc.